# How to implement android custom popup menu?

Tags: android, material-design, popupmenu

I would like to have design popup menu with its item clickable similar to image below in Android project. Any recommend is really appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable)` :

**First**: Inflate option menu

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu)
}
```

**Second**: override `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean = when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.popup_window -> {
        showPopup()
        true
    }   
}
```

Here is the logic of `showPopup()`:

```
private fun showPopup() {
    val anchor =  requireActivity().findViewById<View>(R.id.popup_window) // set the menuOption as anchor so that the popup will display TOP RIGHT of the screen

   val inflater = requireContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater // get layoutinflater from the system service
    val popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popUp_window_options, null) // inflate the popUp_window_options wictch display on popup


    // create the popup window
    val width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    val height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    val focusable = true // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it

    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable)
    popupWindow.elevation = 10f // give it shadow

    PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(popupWindow, anchor, 0, 0, Gravity.CENTER)
    PopupWindowCompat.setWindowLayoutType( popupWindow ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

`R.layout.popUp_window_options` is your layout that contain the options.
Hope it helps. ask any confusion.

After this you will get something like : [image: this]

Comment: Thank you for snipe of code. It is working. Moreover, is it possible to add margin space to the right? So, the popup menu will not stick to the right device screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DialogFragment` with custom layout. So just like you create a fragment, you can create a DialogFragment as well, which will have its own custom layout with feature of dialog box. As following -

```
public class CustomDialogMenu extends DialogFragment {
    
    //global variables

    public static CustomDialogMenu newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        CustomDialogMenu customDialogMenu = new CustomDialogMenu();
        customDialogMenu.setArguments(args);
        return customDialogMenu;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_menu, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ........

}
```

You can use this fragment just like you invoke any other fragment, and `custom_dialog_menu.xml` will have your custom view you want in your dialog menu.

You can invoke this dialog inside a fragment as well. Code as following -

```
private void showCustomDialogMenu() {
    FragmentManager fm = getParentFragmentManager();
    CustomDialogMenu customDialogMenu= CustomDialogMenu.newInstance();
    customDialogMenu.setTargetFragment(this, 300);
    customDialogMenu.show(fm, "custom_dialog_menu");
}
```

For more information follow [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment) code path.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. However, does is able to show the dialog from the right top of the screen as the popup menu behavior ? As this implemented will be the same as popup menu.

Comment: above implementation will create a dialog box for you, if you are strictly looking for pop menu then follow [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/menus-and-popups) code path, or you can simple apply a listener on your menu item to show above dialog box, choice is your :)